# disable auto check out in visual studio 2010 when accidently edited file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Due to accidental key strokes, I end up checking out a lot of files while browing a project in C#. Is it possible to disable check out such that only when I check out the file from perforce explicitly, it allows me to edit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Environment

There see the section Checked-in items. Under Editing drop down select "Prompt for check out"

[image]